# Page flip animation in tabhost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs, android-tabactivity

I created a tab host with 5 tab buttons. When click on button i want to change current page to corresponding page with a flip animation. I tried a lot. Please help. Give me complete project code

Comment: Try being more precise in what you're asking. Show us some of the code you've used.

Comment: You need to show us some code, it will help.

Comment: "Give me complete project code" combined with no so-far attempted code gives **very** low chances of succeeding.